# Nest API in html 5 code

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, firebase, nest-api

For my mobile HTML5 application I have added a script which is included in the index.html file of course.

- Nest.js (see code below)

When I run my application I always get the error that Firebase is not defined.
Which strange because the function is very straight forward:
 --> var dataRef = new Firebase('wss://developer-api.nest.com')

Do I need the included extra code?

```js
/**
 *  Copyright 2014 Nest Labs Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 *  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 *  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 *  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 */
/* globals $, Firebase */
'use strict';

var nestToken = $.cookie('https://api.home.nest.com/oauth2/access_token?client_id=xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=authorization_code'),
    thermostat = {},
    structure  = {};

if (nestToken) { // Simple check for token

  // Create a reference to the API using the provided token
  var dataRef = new Firebase('wss://developer-api.nest.com');
  dataRef.auth(nestToken);

  // in a production client we would want to
  // handle auth errors here.

} else {
  // No auth token, go get one
  window.location.replace('/auth/nest');
}

/**
  The appropriate version of target temperature to display is based on
  the following parameters:

  * hvac_mode (C or F)
  * temperature_scale (range, heat, cool, or off)

  When hvac_mode is 'range' we display both the low and the high setpoints like:

    68 • 80° F

  For 'heat' or 'cool' just the temperature is displayed

    70° F

  For 'off' we show that the thermostat is off:

    OFF

  Away modes are handled separately

  @method
  @param object thermostat model
  @returns undefined
*/
function updateTemperatureDisplay (thermostat) {
  var scale = thermostat.temperature_scale.toLowerCase();

  // For Heat • Cool mode, we display a range of temperatures
  // we support displaying but not changing temps in this mode
  if (thermostat.hvac_mode === 'range') {
    $('#target-temperature .temp').text(
      thermostat['target_temperature_low_' + scale] + ' • ' +
      thermostat['target_temperature_high_' + scale]
     );

  // Display the string 'off' when the thermostat is turned off
  } else if (thermostat.hvac_mode === 'off') {
    $('#target-temperature .temp').text('off');

  // Otherwise just display the target temperature
  } else {
    $('#target-temperature .temp').text(thermostat['target_temperature_' + scale] + '°');
  }

  // Update ambient temperature display
  $('#ambient-temperature .temp').text(thermostat['ambient_temperature_' + scale] + '°');
}

/**
  Updates the thermostat view with the latests data

  * Temperature scale
  * HVAC mode
  * Target and ambient temperatures
  * Device name

  @method
  @param object thermostat model
  @returns undefined
*/
function updateThermostatView(thermostat) {
  var scale = thermostat.temperature_scale;

  $('.temperature-scale').text(scale);
  $('#target-temperature .hvac-mode').text(thermostat.hvac_mode);
  $('#device-name').text(thermostat.name);
  updateTemperatureDisplay(thermostat);
}

/**
  Updates the structure's home/away state by
  adding the class 'home' when the structure is
  set to home, and removing it when in any away state

  @method
  @param object structure
  @returns undefined
*/
function updateStructureView (structure) {
  if (structure.away === 'home') {
    $('#target-temperature').addClass('home');
  } else {
    $('#target-temperature').removeClass('home');
  }
}

/**
  Updates the thermostat's target temperature
  by the specified number of degrees in the
  specified scale. If a type is specified, it
  will be used to set just that target temperature
  type

  @method
  @param Number degrees
  @param String temperature scale
  @param String type, high or low. Used in heat-cool mode (optional)
  @returns undefined
*/
function adjustTemperature(degrees, scale, type) {
  scale = scale.toLowerCase();
  type = type ? type + '_' : '';
  var newTemp = thermostat['target_temperature_' + scale] + degrees,
      path = 'devices/thermostats/' + thermostat.device_id + '/target_temperature_' + type + scale;

  if (thermostat.is_using_emergency_heat) {
    console.error("Can't adjust target temperature while using emergency heat.");
  } else if (thermostat.hvac_mode === 'heat-cool' && !type) {
    console.error("Can't adjust target temperature while in Heat • Cool mode, use target_temperature_high/low instead.");
  } else if (type && thermostat.hvac_mode !== 'heat-cool') {
    console.error("Can't adjust target temperature " + type + " while in " + thermostat.hvac_mode +  " mode, use target_temperature instead.");
  } else if (structure.away.indexOf('away') > -1) {
    console.error("Can't adjust target temperature while structure is set to Away or Auto-away.");
  } else { // ok to set target temperature
    dataRef.child(path).set(newTemp);
  }
}

/**
  When the user clicks the up button,
  adjust the temperature up 1 degree F
  or 0.5 degrees C

*/
$('#up-button').on('click', function () {
  var scale = thermostat.temperature_scale,
      adjustment = scale === 'F' ? +1 : +0.5;
  adjustTemperature(adjustment, scale);
});

/**
  When the user clicks the down button,
  adjust the temperature down 1 degree F
  or 0.5 degrees C

*/
$('#down-button').on('click', function () {
  var scale = thermostat.temperature_scale,
      adjustment = scale === 'F' ? -1 : -0.5;
  adjustTemperature(adjustment, scale);
});

/**
  When the user clicks the heating up button,
  adjust the temperature up 1 degree F
  or 0.5 degrees C

*/
$('#up-button-heat').on('click', function () {
  var scale = thermostat.temperature_scale,
      adjustment = scale === 'F' ? +1 : +0.5;
  adjustTemperature(adjustment, scale, 'heat');
});

/**
  When the user clicks the heating down button,
  adjust the temperature down 1 degree F
  or 0.5 degrees C

*/
$('#down-button-heat').on('click', function () {
  var scale = thermostat.temperature_scale,
      adjustment = scale === 'F' ? -1 : -0.5;
  adjustTemperature(adjustment, scale, 'heat');
});

/**
  When the user clicks the cooling up button,
  adjust the temperature up 1 degree F
  or 0.5 degrees C

*/
$('#up-button-cool').on('click', function () {
  var scale = thermostat.temperature_scale,
      adjustment = scale === 'F' ? +1 : +0.5;
  adjustTemperature(adjustment, scale, 'cool');
});

/**
  When the user clicks the cooling down button,
  adjust the temperature down 1 degree F
  or 0.5 degrees C

*/
$('#down-button-cool').on('click', function () {
  var scale = thermostat.temperature_scale,
      adjustment = scale === 'F' ? -1 : -0.5;
  adjustTemperature(adjustment, scale, 'cool');
});

/**
  Utility method to return the first child
  value of the passed in object.

  @method
  @param object
  @returns object
*/
function firstChild(object) {
  for(var key in object) {
    return object[key];
  }
}

/**
  Start listening for changes on this account,
  update appropriate views as data changes.

*/
dataRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.val();

  // For simplicity, we only care about the first
  // thermostat in the first structure
  structure = firstChild(data.structures),
  thermostat = data.devices.thermostats[structure.thermostats[0]];

  // TAH-361, device_id does not match the device's path ID
  thermostat.device_id = structure.thermostats[0];

  updateThermostatView(thermostat);
  updateStructureView(structure);

});
```

Comment: anyone has some more information? I'm still stuck

Comment: Yes, the Firebause function is now working.

Comment: Only thing that is now not working is the Firebase.auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the [Firebase javascript API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/) in your `index.html`, before `nest.js`.

> Do i need it to import in the main index.html or in the scriot file of nest.js itself?

In general you can do either. It is a good practice to include the source files as separate script tags in your `index.html`, and use an automated build process (like [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat)) to concatenate them before distribution.

*PS: I highly suggest you to renew your api token. It's not that hard to find out the missing characters of your client_id*

Answer (score 0):

It appears that nest.js is connecting to a back-end database service called [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/). The connection is a secure web socket connection; its URI is passed into the constructor for the firebase class. To use the firebase constructor, I believe you need to import the firebase api [javascript file](https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.3.2/firebase.js).

Comment: Do i need it to import in the main index.html or in the scriot file of nest.js itself?

Comment: Either way works, but I prefer to include it in the index.html. Just make sure to include the firebase.js script tag before the nest.js script tag.